# Result management in python Django

Tags: python, django

I am designing a web application in python `Django` with `postgres` as database, for multiple schools. Every school will have a separate login and only the owner data is displayed.

1. The main problem I am facing in this design is that these schools conduct exams based on books not on subjects (Like: English, Hindi, Maths, Science, Social, …) like in regular schools. These schools follow different book. Every school has their own syllabus. These books (as  syllabus) might change almost every year. Which means that the syllabus is not a permanent syllabus, might change as and when required.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agXPq.jpg)

In the above example the school has a syllabus based on book in the Academic year 2019-20 which was changed in academic year 2020-21 as they introduced New Book7 and New Book 8. And the same is with other schools. Syllabus for each school is different and in different academic years.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUb96.jpg)

2. The other challenge is the result management of these schools. Since the  books (syllabus) changes almost every year, how to maintain the results of student of that particular academic year in the database.

Can any one help me is structuring this task please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be better to add the pictures directly in your question (instead of the link), and also put any attempts you might have tried. The scope of this question looks actually too big to be answered (and too much text... not easy to read). The purpose of SO is not to have other people **do** tasks, but rather answering questions and helping people when **they** perform their tasks.

Comment: Hi, to complement my previous comment, it is not exactly clear what you need. Do you need help on how to organize the database? If so, the fact that you try to do a web app in Django is quite irrelevant? I suggest you try to simplify the format and clarify your question.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT.
Thank you for your response. I tried to add pics but not able to.. any how i am sorry if the Question is too complicated. I have tried this task. was able to create different logins successfully for diff schools. but stuck at a point where i have to manage the results. These schools change their syllabus almost every year or two. so how to manage the database or what will be the logic so that the previous years record(result) won't effect when new record (result) is created with the new syllabus. and more over the syllabus of each school is different.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT.
The Exams are conducted based on Books not Subjects.

Comment: For picture, usually copy-paste a picture content or file or drag-drop file to the text zone where you enter the text is enough.

For your question, I'm not an expert in database, but would it be possible to have one database with the history of syllabus for each school in time and another db with all students, organized per students?

Comment: I was able to complete a similar kind of project for a single school in MS Access Database, which kept the history of syllabus and the latest updated syllabus without disturbing the previous records of students as well but not able to in python Django.

Comment: But is it really related to Django or rather PostgreSQL?

Comment: Actually Both. Postgres is the database. And python django, i am using as the web application design. if possible can you share your email, i will send you the screen shots of what i have done so far.

Comment: :) Actually, I am not familiar with either Django or PostGres ... I was just trying to help you clarify your question because it is very massive and unfortunately does not incite people to take the time to read and answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my several messages, your question is not exactly clear on your main issue (2 problems, and we don't see much the relation with Django).

I am not familiar with Databases, Django, or PostGres so my suggestion might be a bit off.

Maybe you could try to store the syllabus separately from the School (since many schools might choose a given syllabus for a particular year, anyway).

Then you could have a list of scores for each student for each year: this should solve your point #2.

This is my attempt to conceptualize this suggestion (which is more "Object-Oriented" rather than database, but that might give some direction):

[image: Description Database]

FYI: to upload a picture, you can just copy-paste the file content in the edit area, or drag&drop the file in it. You will then have an option to push the file. Just edit the description of the file and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a similar kind of set up however Syllabus and Book in one table, let me try with what you have suggested and i will get back to you if any more issues.